# Visual representation of sets

Tags: algorithm, graphics, set, data-representation

I have some experimental data and I have decided to represent them as sets.

Let's say, there is a main set called **E={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s}** (*blue circle*) and several sub-sets **B** (*red dashed ellipses*) which contains elements from main set **E**.

I need to represent these sub-sets in the main set **E** and show their intersections, more or less similar to the figure below.

That's why I need some algorithms (with an example) to draw that figure. Preferably in PHP or Javascript (*using SVG specification*), because I am going to implement this problem in a Web Application.

[image: Graphical representation of set-covering problem]

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Do your data have a fixed position, or must the algorithm lays them out?

Comment: @Nicolas. Generally no, they don't have a fixed positions. I have just sets and need to represent them in a good way. So as you proposed some algorithm could locate them randomly

Comment: Can sets with no intersecting elements intersect visually?

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that this is something that a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) would be good at, because:

1. The total path length of all subset perimeters could be used as the fitness function (minimising this will tend to give "good" solutions lacking long skinny subsets), and this function is continuous.
2. It should be straightforward to implement mutation (jiggle the positions of one or more elements) and crossover (swap the positions of some elements).

Another important suggestion for the fitness function: **heavily penalise** any solution where one subset's perimeter encloses an element that does not belong to that set.

My suggestion is to work with convex hulls of elements for subset perimeters (or possibly even bounding boxes, which are even simpler).  Once optimal locations have been decided, you can draw the perimeters using [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline) to make them nice and smooth.